# Dayjs and plain date objects give different difference

Tags: javascript, date, dayjs

At [this link](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference) of the Dayjs library you will read this:

```
const date1 = dayjs('2019-01-25')
const date2 = dayjs('2018-06-05')
date1.diff(date2) // 20214000000 default milliseconds
```

But if you type in the console, you'll get this:

```
new Date(2019,0,25) - new Date(2018,5,5)
// result: 20221200000
```

Why the difference?

Comment: It actually depends on the timezone you run it in - there are many factors involved that change the time between the two dates across different timezones

Comment: The difference in the two time values is 7200000 ms, which is 2 hours. 1 hour of that can be attributed to daylight saving given *dayjs* likely parses the strings as UTC but the Date constructor will treat them as local. For me, `new Date(2019,0,25) - new Date(2018,5,5)` returns 20217600000, which is 1 hour different from 20221200000, so I guess the host in that case was set to a region with daylight saving since my system is set to ignore DST.

Comment: UTC should not matter, because it takes the difference between the same timezones, still wondering what happened ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
const dayjs = require("dayjs")

const date1 = dayjs("2019-01-25")
const date2 = dayjs("2018-06-05")
console.log(date1.diff(date2)) // 20214000000

console.log(new Date(2019, 0, 25) - new Date(2018, 5, 5)) // 20214000000
console.log(new Date(2019, 0, 25).getTime() - new Date(2018, 5, 5).getTime()) // 20214000000
```

You can get the timestamp of `Date` with the `.getTime()` function, and in this case you are just doing `1548381600000 - 1528167600000`. I'm not sure how did you get `20221200000` but this value is just wrong.